# double inner join in access db

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I need to get some data from two tables, 1 people, 2 tasks,
The following query in SQL works, and Access does not work

```
 SELECT     Task_Id,
            e2.emploeey_name AS W_FROM,
            e1.emploeey_name AS W_TO,
            t.Task_Details
 FROM       tasks AS T
 INNER JOIN Employees AS e1 ON e1.Emploeey_id = T.Task_To
 INNER JOIN Employees AS e2 ON e2.Emploeey_id = T.write_From
```

I tried many ways, and I searched in Google and I did not find an answer
If anyone has a solution I would appreciate it very

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you tried it with parentheses? MS Access requires (i.e. likes) parentheses around multiple JOINS:

```
 SELECT     Task_Id,
            e2.emploeey_name AS W_FROM,
            e1.emploeey_name AS W_TO,
            t.Task_Details
 FROM       
 (
      tasks AS T
      INNER JOIN Employees AS e1 
           ON e1.Emploeey_id = T.Task_To
 )
 INNER JOIN Employees AS e2 
      ON e2.Emploeey_id = T.write_From
```

Comment: And by "likes" you mean "requires"

Comment: Thanks so much, after 10 hours of searching, works great, thanks again