# Access SQL selecting multiple columns from linked tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables. Table A:

```
First_name Last_name score 
   Joo      jojo      100
   Jake      Tim       30
```

Table B:

```
Name  length
Joo     3
Jake    4
Jojo    4
Tim     3
```

The PK for A is join of FIrst and last name,  for B pk is name. If I want to print something like this:

```
First_name Last_name score  First_name_length   Last_name_length
```

How should I fix from the following code:

```
Select A.*, B.length
From A,B
Where A.First_name=B.Name or A.Last_name=B.Name;
```

Thanks.

Update: I solved the problem with a little change from the answer below by @paqogomez. In access, with double inner join, one should use ( ), please check this post. Thank you all for your kindly help.

[double inner join in access db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10332303/double-inner-join-in-access-db)

Comment: Please clarify if table B is used to store the length of the First/Last names

Comment: Yes, B is used to store the length

Comment: well in that case my answer is the simplest query to get the desired result

Comment: The difficult part in my opinion is I don't know how to deal with Table B, because A.last_name and A.First_name both relate to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joining to your name table twice will accomplish this:

```
select
  b1.name as First_name,
  b2.name as Last_name,
  a.score as score,
  b1.length as First_name_length,
  b2.length as Last_name_length
from
  (a
  inner join b as b1 on a.First_name = b1.name)
  inner join b as b2 on a.Last_name = b2.name
```

The problem you will run into however is if 2 people have the same first or last name.  It would be better to clean up your data and give each user an unique value.

EDIT:

I assume that you want to use the value from your table `B`, if you are really just getting the string length of the name, then please use @Srikanth's answer.

While OP is using Access, I made [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c8866/1) using sql server that shows it working.

Parens above added for [access's double inner join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10332303/double-inner-join-in-access-db)

Comment: Thanks, inner join seems to be the best choise.

Comment: It return syntax error, should I define b1 or b2 first please? Thanks again

Comment: It seems doesn't like the second inner join, should add "," between them please? thanks.

Comment: @henduoqian No, you are using older sql 89 syntax in your OP.  With `inner join` (sql 92 syntax) there is no comma between the tables.  You can see it working in the fiddle that I posted.

Comment: @henduoqian, if you're getting an error, please show me the exact message.

Comment: Thanks for the continue reply. It shows"Syntax error(missing operator) in query expression'GAMES.[Home team]=TEAMS1.Name inner join TEAMS as TEAMS2 on GAMES.[Visiting team]=TEAMS2.Nam'. PS: I use a different table names here.

Comment: @henduoqian Using [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8aeb5) post your whole query.

Comment: @henduoqian, this is sounding like it is probably another question.  If I can see the syntax of your changes, i'm sure I could fix them.  If you change your tables to their real names, i'll create a proper query.  However, you might want to just post another question.

Comment: I see what is going on now. Access use a different format of double inner join, please check my update. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The following code with [Len](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/access-help/len-function-HA001228874.aspx) is sufficient for the desired output

```
Select First_name, 
       Last_name, 
       score,  
       len(First_name) AS First_name_length, 
       len(Last_name) AS Last_name_length
From A
```

Comment: lol.. i didnt even consider that he was just looking for the length of the string name.  This would be the answer if that is the case. +1

Comment: Yeah, initially I thought of using two joins similar to yours but with another glance at the data in table B I felt this should do the job

Comment: It could be simply poor example data, but we need clarification from OP to be sure.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Really open eyes for me. But I am not looking for string length only, just want to know how to select column from linked tables. But your answer is really a short cut and wise idea.