# SQL update with inner join on 2 additional tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am struggling with the following query on ms-access :

```
UPDATE
(
    (
    DWH_TICKERS_LIST
    INNER JOIN  ODS_PAGE_HEADER_INFO ON ODS_PAGE_HEADER_INFO.TICKER_CODE = DWH_TICKERS_LIST.TICKERS_LIST__TICKER
    ) 
INNER JOIN SECTOR ON SECTOR.NAME = DWH_TICKERS_LIST.TICKERS_LIST__NAME
)
SET 
    DWH_TICKERS_LIST.TICKERS_LIST__ISIN_CODE             = ODS_PAGE_HEADER_INFO.ISIN_CODE
,   DWH_TICKERS_LIST.TICKERS_LIST__CURR                  = ODS_PAGE_HEADER_INFO.CURR
,   DWH_TICKERS_LIST.TICKERS_LIST__SECTOR_FK             = SECTOR.SECTOR_PK
,   DWH_TICKERS_LIST.TICKERS_LIST__TOTALVOLUME           = ODS_PAGE_HEADER_INFO.TOTALVOLUME
,   DWH_TICKERS_LIST.TICKERS_LIST__ELIGIBILITY_SRD       = ODS_PAGE_HEADER_INFO.ELIGIBILITY_SRD
,   DWH_TICKERS_LIST.TICKERS_LIST__ELIGIBILITY_PEA       = ODS_PAGE_HEADER_INFO.ELIGIBILITY_PEA
,   DWH_TICKERS_LIST.TICKERS_LIST__ELIGIBILITY_22H       = ODS_PAGE_HEADER_INFO.ELIGIBILITY_22H
,   DWH_TICKERS_LIST.DWH_TICKERS_LIST__UPDATE_DATETIME   = Now()
```

I got inspired from [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10332303/double-inner-join-in-access-db).
However I get that error :

```
sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError: (pyodbc.Error) ('07002', '[07002] [Microsoft][Pilote ODBC Microsoft Access] Trop peu de paramètres. 1 attendu. (-3010) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

i.e. too few parameters, 1 expected.

Any idea how to correct this?

Comment: Where do you see a `FROM` in the statement? The syntax is valid. `UPDATE tables` can contain JOINs. @Dai

Comment: @Andre Thank you for correcting me - I had no idea Access could do that. I can't find any examples or hints in Access' online documentation. (As for the `UPDATE FROM` synax - that's because I spent too much time with SQL Server)

Comment: Yeah, since you can't do `UPDATE .. FROM x JOIN y` in Access, it is imperative that there is another way. If you use the query designer to create an update query with multiple tables, it comes automatically. @Dai

Comment: @Andre There's always "another way" in Access, yes - but that invariably boils-down to having to use VBA+DAO and ISAM patterns instead of set-based SQL - how else can you traverse a table representing a graph as there's no support for recursive CTE queries, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Name` is a [reserved word](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/reserved-words) in some contexts, although it is not listed in the [Access SQL reserved words](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sql-reserved-words-b899948b-0e1c-4b56-9622-a03f8f07cfc8).

Nevertheless try enclosing it in brackets: `SECTOR.[NAME]`

The outer parentheses surrounding the JOIN list are not needed (but don't hurt probably).

If `[NAME]` doesn't help, the most probable cause is that you have a typo somewhere in your field names.

You can improve readability by using short aliases for table names:

```
UPDATE
    (
    DWH_TICKERS_LIST AS tl
    INNER JOIN  ODS_PAGE_HEADER_INFO AS hi 
      ON hi.TICKER_CODE = tl.TICKERS_LIST__TICKER
    ) 
    INNER JOIN SECTOR AS s ON s.[NAME] = tl.TICKERS_LIST__NAME

SET 
    tl.TICKERS_LIST__ISIN_CODE             = hi.ISIN_CODE
,   tl.TICKERS_LIST__CURR                  = hi.CURR
,   tl.TICKERS_LIST__SECTOR_FK             = s.SECTOR_PK
etc.
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, how does Access know which table is the target of the `UPDATE` DML? Does it always go with the topmost/first-mentioned table, or does it let you specify any table alias in the `SET` clause? I assume it only lets you `UPDATE` 1 table per statement too, so you can't do `UPDATE ( x INNER JOIN y ON x.a = y.a ) SET x.a = 1, y.b = 2`?

Comment: That's a good question, I don't think I ever needed this - but you can actually run an update that modifies 2 tables, at least in an Access database. It may very well not work with linked ODBC tables from a DB server. And since it would be really confusing code IMHO, it's better not to use it. :-) @Dai